# Efficient redrawing of a line chart with Meteor and d3.js

Tags: meteor, d3.js

What is an efficient method to redraw a line graph reactively in Meteor, using d3.js?

I have a method that works, and while it's "fast enough" for now, I do not like it.

My current method is to use an Observer on a query, and use that to maintain a related object that d3.js can use to render from, thus in the normal redraw path no Meteor calls are made.

I am not happy with this, as it requires a sort of the keys.  Keys are fixed points in time, so the Doctor can't modify them...  I mean the keys are time points (every 600 seconds, for instance) and the values are currently an object with one or more things I wish to plot as on the X axis.

Every time something changes, I update this related object and basically call the usual d3.js magic to select the line, and update it.  This is really little more than a more efficient way to redraw the whole graph.

As the data points increase, so does the time taken to redraw.  I use _.throttle() with a 500 ms gate to restrict redrawing to a reasonable rate.

Updates are frequent, but typically only to the last item, as it updates the max, min, average, and current values for that time point as new data arrives.

If I were plotting circles, this would be much easier as I could only redraw a single circle, touching only one data point.  All the examples I've seen use circles, bar graphs, etc. which are all relatively easy to update efficiently.  But, a line chart...  that's a challenge!

I considered making it up of a lot of little line segments, but I also like the "basis" interpolation look better than linear.

How are people doing this in the wild?

Comment: I'm a little curious why this question was down-voted without a comment about why...

Comment: I hope you have gone through this http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ ...

Comment: I have, and while they are all useful, I also think they are no more efficient than what I'm doing now.  I did find that maintaining that related object sped redraws up by nearly 40x, but it still seems to consume a fair amount of CPU in the browser.  I typically have 16 lines consisting of at least 100 points each -- this didn't seem like too much given some of those examples.